# how to read number and print it out digit by digit

Tags: plsqldeveloper

1. Write a program to read in a number and print it out digit by digit, as a series of words. For example, the number 523 would be printed as "five two three".  Use decode function within a for loop.  Display the results on the screen using dbms_output.put_line.

Comment: What have you got so far? Any attempt?

Comment: This is an instruction rather than an a question. It reads suspiciously like a homework exercise you've been set :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly extensive forum thread on this by the popular Tom Kyte:

[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650)